# unique string route base for zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, routes

i want to have some route for shortest url method for zend framework.

i have a router like this

```
http://mysite.org/en/articles/view/id/34/title/MyUniqueArticleTitleInEnglish
```

i can easily change to

```
http://mysite.org/en/viewarticle/MyUniqueArticleTitleInEnglish
```

i want to have something like this

```
http://mysite.org/MyUniqueArticleTitleInEnglish
```

that check if unique title not available check for 'MyUniqueArticleTitleInEnglish' controller like default route.

what must i do?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a routing stack that goes to the desired controller for scenario 3 if there is only one parameter in the url and goes to a 'normal' module/controller/action route if more params are supplied. Should look like:

```xml
routes.shortest.route = "/:slug"
routes.shortest.defaults.module = public
routes.shortest.defaults.controller = article
routes.shortest.defaults.action = show

routes.default.route = ":module/:controller/:action"
routes.default.defaults.controller = index
routes.default.defaults.action = index
```

(untested but should work)